# Load object in game mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building an application that measures different parts of human body. For that every time new human body will be uploaded in .obj file from external disk, so the problem is I cannot create a prefabs as object is not fixed and I have to load an object at runtime.

I have tried with OBJLoader extension, but OBJLoader is using UnityEditor so it is not working after build.

Is there is any solution that can load .obj file from external disk even after build.

I am building app for Windows(.exe).

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/49547

Comment: yes, that OBJLoader class is using UnityEditor which is not working after build

Answer (score 1):

To load a 3D static model in obj format at runtime, follow these steps:

1. rename the obj files to `*.bytes`/`*.txt` or [other supported formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html).
2. Load the file into [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html)

   ```
   TextAsset data = Resources.Load("model.bytes") as TextAsset;
   ```
3. Parse the string ([`data.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset-text.html)) and extract the mesh data (vertex positions, indices, uv0, uv1 and so on) from it. The obj format is very easy to parse and there are also many plugins and open-source projects available.
4. Create a `Mesh` and fill it with the mesh data and assign it to the `MeshFilter` of a `GameObject`.

   ```
   Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
   GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
   mesh.vertices = newVertices;
   mesh.uv = newUV;
   mesh.triangles = newTriangles;
   ```

The material info can also be extracted from `*.mtl` files. Just follow the similar steps: create `Material` with a proper shader, assign textures to the material and assign the material to the `sharedMaterial` of the `MeshRenderer` of the `GameObject`.

Comment: Also be aware of the Unity limit of ~60k vertices when generating a mesh.

Comment: Can you elaborate 3rd point, because as per me you are trying to say to read object file manually